# Call an function after another with Axios

Tags: javascript, api, axios

I need to call an `API`, after getting it's success value it will come to it's calling function.
But alas! Calling function is executing before finishing it's calling....

How can I do this?

```
async callStoreApi(urlNoProtocol) {
     const fullUrl = 'https://example.com/users';
     let response = '';
     response = await axios.get(fullUrl);
     console.log("Response in Axios: ", response);
 },
 checkUrl(){
   let response = this.callStoreApi();
   console.log("Response from checkUrl: ", response);
}
```

In console:

```
Response from checkUrl: ...
Response in Axios: .....
```

Comment: `callStoreApi` doesn't return anything ... so, it'll return a Promise that resolves to `undefined` - is that what you expected?

Comment: Use [then and catch](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2020/11/comparison-async-await-versus-then-catch/)

Comment: the reason `Response from checkUrl` is executing first is because you're not waiting for the Promise returned by `callStoreApi` to resolve ...

Comment: I want the response data.

Comment: How can I wait for that, can you give me example answer?

Comment: 1. In `callStoreApi`, return the `axios.get(fulUrl)`: `return axios.get(....)`. 2. Inside `checkUrl`, call `then` method on `this.callStoreApi`: `this.callStoreApi.then(response => { ... })` or just `await` it: `await this.callStoreApi`.

Comment: if you want response, return response

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to add `await` infront of `this.callStoreApi()`

```js
async callStoreApi(urlNoProtocol) {
  const fullUrl = 'https://example.com/users';
  let response = '';
  response = await axios.get(fullUrl);
  console.log("Response in Axios: ", response);
},

async checkUrl() {
   const response = await this.callStoreApi();

   console.log("Response from checkUrl: ", response);
}
```

Otherwise, it will call `this.callStoreApi()` but stores the promise in `response` not the result itself.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but with . then syntax would be a solution like this:

```
 axios
    .get(URL)
    .then((response) => {
      console.log("Response in Axios: ", response)
      return response
    })
    .then((data) => console.log(data.callStoreApi()))
    .catch((err) => console.log(err))
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because when you use async your function will always return a promise so using await isn't really 'thread blocking' (well it is but only in the async function)

so since callStoreApi() is a promise it will be executed as a promise so response is not your real data but a promise instead you should use .then() or use again an async await like this

```
async callStoreApi(urlNoProtocol) {
     const fullUrl = 'https://example.com/users';
     let response = '';
     response = await axios.get(fullUrl);
     console.log("Response in Axios: ", response);
 },
 async checkUrl(){
   let response = await this.callStoreApi();
   console.log("Response from checkUrl: ", response);
}
```

remember that now check url return also a promise if you use async ;)